# Facebook ignores Open Graph meta data of my page

Tags: php, html, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I am going crazy over this, like going gray haired instantly. 
I hope someone can help me.

I am currently developing a website which has accommodations.
They have a page for each accommodation with details of that item.

Before the document is put out to the browser, I collect all meta data for Open Graph with php and output it all in the head of the document with the use of og meta tags.

A strange thing happens at all these pages, for example http://parclaclusure.internetanders.nl/nl/accommodaties/lodgetenten/

Because when I use the Facebook Debugger on that url it comes up with different results than the browser gives me in the source code.

The things I did to rule out any problems on my part:

- Checked the HTML with the W3C validator, it checks out, no errors
- Used an extra parameter to ensure that de meta data is not cached @ Facebook, like adding ?test=1234 to the url
- Search on Stackoverflow (and the rest of the interwebs) for the same problem, couldn't find any

Can anyone point out what's wrong with my og meta tags? or why they are ignored/changed in Facebook. (Facebook uses the og meta data of a page located 1 step higher -> http://parclaclusure.internetanders.nl/nl/accommodaties/)

Note: Please be discrete with the website address, because it's a development environment and not yet meant to go public, live or viral :P, thanks!

Comment: What's the issue? What's the debugger showing?

Comment: The Debugger shows different content for the og meta tags, than the ones that are on the page. Look at the difference between the source code @ http://parclaclusure.internetanders.nl/nl/accommodaties/lodgetenten/ and what Facebook Debugger outputs as og meta data from its scraper

Comment: It's the same. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fparclaclusure.internetanders.nl%2Fnl%2Faccommodaties%2Flodgetenten%2F

Comment: Nope, for example the debugger picks up <meta property="og:title" content="Accommodaties | Camping Parc La Clusure - ****ANWB vakantiepark, in het hart van Belgische Ardennen" /> while the source code of the page gives <meta property="og:title" content="Lodgetenten - Accommodaties | Camping Parc La Clusure - ****ANWB vakantiepark, in het hart van Belgische Ardennen" />. The only thing that is the same is the og:url.

Comment: Your source code has this: `<meta property="og:title" content="Accommodaties | Camping Parc La Clusure - ****ANWB vakantiepark, in het hart van Belgische Ardennen" />`

Comment: Strange, then I have different results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a session problem. I have the feeling a session is set after all the required data is loaded.

What I notice is that after a page refresh I see different content.
Hope this helps...

Comment: I feel so stupid now, the reason i didn't spot it was because I was testing constantly under the umbrella of my already set session... thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your page with the OpenGraph Debugger : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

It will update the content of your OG tags in Facebook. It doesn't update the content each time someone share your page, only on debug.

EDIT : On your code :

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://parclaclusure.internetanders.nl/uploads/defaults/default.facebook.png" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://parclaclusure.internetanders.nl/uploads/images/300x300-e04fcee6a2ba22c917d1c45e6c61b926.jpg" />
 <meta property="og:image" content="http://parclaclusure.internetanders.nl/uploads/images/300x300-0cb0ca4759b278c22f075c781a628956.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://parclaclusure.internetanders.nl/uploads/images/300x300-6c63e58a9ba8d555f277d34d2daeddc5.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://parclaclusure.internetanders.nl/uploads/images/300x300-73f0f66a0d05d0bf570254f1eb7072f8.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://parclaclusure.internetanders.nl/uploads/images/300x300-063fcc1f10db6bdb3e2d3c4d053f76db.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://parclaclusure.internetanders.nl/uploads/images/300x300-1c0526d2cc3c916fc3c67d0b83e6f7f9.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://parclaclusure.internetanders.nl/uploads/images/300x300-a850047c2225b1b9e5d5fddae1d1c7bf.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image"  content="http://parclaclusure.internetanders.nl/uploads/images/300x300-25094d3a08fb093983dedffdcaf14c88.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://parclaclusure.internetanders.nl/uploads/images/300x300-3414c0ad4780a27ad8326007ec3987ae.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://parclaclusure.internetanders.nl/uploads/images/300x300-845b24160e9fe438e851a6b2fb17af17.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://parclaclusure.internetanders.nl/uploads/images/300x300-0e2b4efe0d30745ea34afc9b01bb6eb4.jpg" />
```

What do you expect from this ? You are supposed to have only one OG:image metatag...

Comment: That's exactly what I did, i even made sure it is not cached in the debugger by adding ?test=1234 at the end of the url in the debugger